# Не работает :last-of-type

Tags: html, css3

В htm моя сетка построена так - в footer в блоке nav, я создал список  из однотипны элементов, также они еще являются ссылками

```html
<nav class="footer__links">
    <ul class="footer__link-list">
        <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Карты</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Погода</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Расписание</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Календарь</a></li>
        <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Путешествия</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

И мне необходимо последнему элементу убрать отступ: :last-of-type, :last-child, :nth-last-of-type() и другие не работают.

Ведь last-of-type анализирует html, в силу того, что у меня каждый тег "а" обернут в li он не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Просто обращайтесь не к `a:last-child`, а к `li:last-child`

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer__link-list li:last-child .footer__link {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer__link-list">
  <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Карты</a></li>
  <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Погода</a></li>
  <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Расписание</a></li>
  <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Календарь</a></li>
  <li><a class="footer__link" href="#" target="_blank">Путешествия</a></li>
</ul>
```

Потому что у `li` нет других `child`-ов кроме `a`

Если бы в `li` были несколько узлов, тогда бы `a:last-child` применялся к тегам a которые находятся последними